# why the padding property affects RecyclerView drag

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I used [ItemTouchHelper](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/helper/ItemTouchHelper.html) to implements the drag operation `RecyclerView`, and set the `android:clipChildren="false"` to make it could drag out of the `RecyclerView's` rect range. The layout file is below:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#999999"
android:clipChildren="false"
tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@null"
    app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayoutSpringBehavior">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_collapsing"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@null"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/delete"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:background="#99999999"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="delete"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/main_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:title="">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/left_bar_width"
    android:layoutAnimation="@anim/anim_layout"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

It worked fine till now:

[image]

But ***the problem is***, when I added padding, such as android:paddingTop="10dp", to the RecyclerView, it failed to drag out of the RecyclerView range:
[image]

How to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

`android:clipToPadding=false` should fix the issue